# Does ElasticSearch JavaScript API supports simple "PUT"?

Tags: elasticsearch

The core ElasticSearch API supports `PUT` verb - `PUT <index>/<type>/<id>` -- which functions as an UPSERT command - if the document does not exist, PUT creates it, otherwise it replaces the document with the new version.  Does the elasticsearch-js have corresponding functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I should have used [`client.index()`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-index) -- which either creates or updates.